# Storing a float value in SQLite changes the decimal precision in Room DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to store the price in my room database. I can have the decimal precision of 2 decimals or of 3 decimals depending on the country my app is being used at.

While storing the float or even the double value in the sqlite database using the room library of android, it changes the value. For eg:
14.54 is stored as 14.539999961853

While debugging I can find the value is 14.54 only in the list that I pass to insert. But while checking for the saved records from the SQLite Browser app for windows. I see that the values have changed. I had manually entered a query using the sqlite browser and the value saves as is (the float value without changing the precision). Eg:

```
("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ItemPrice) VALUES (14.54)");
```

The above query executes successfully and inserts the float of 14.54

But in android using the following

```
@Insert 
Long[] saveMyTable(final List<MYTABLE> myTable);
```

MyTable entity have a field as

```
public float ItemPrice;
```

while inserting the above query the values are changed

I have also tried changing the data type in the DB Schema as real, float, double. But nothing helps.

Comment: Not possible!! I am using float in my room model class and its working fine. Have you cast your value with float while inserting data?

Comment: Not manually. I was using float, but while saving float(in code) to double(in DB) it auto casts the value and stores the huge decimals number. My below mentioned answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had float in my code and in db schema it was double(Though dosent mean anything)

But I did the fllowing:
1. Use the same datatype both in code and db(I used double for precision)
2. While storing the values. I rounded off the double to my needs.

```
public static short COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAX_DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL;//Dynamically set
private static int ROUNDING_MODE = BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN;

public double roundedDouble(double doubleValue) {
    return new 
BigDecimal(doubleValue).setScale(COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAX_DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL, 
ROUNDING_MODE).doubleValue();
}
```

3. The above method will return me a double with 2 or 3 decimals depending what I set in COUNTRY_CURRENCY_MAX_DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL valiable.
4. Finally I store the value in the DB.

Ps: Without the above method, my float was always converitng to double with default decimals and I always get the huge value.

Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

i am using room db for demo app that time i am store value same value define above.
first of define pojo class for table like..

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private double ItemPrice;

public double getItemPrice() {
    return ItemPrice;
}

public void setItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
    ItemPrice = itemPrice;
}
```

}

then after define dao class like...

```
@Dao
public interface MyTableDao {
@Insert
void insertData(MyTable myTable);

}
```

then after define db inside table like ...

```
@Database(entities = {MyTable.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract MyTableDao getTableDao();
}
```

then after used below code inside main activiy define db name,and version and also insert data...

```
public class DbInsert extends AppCompatActivity {
AppDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "MyDb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
    myTable.setItemPrice(14.54);
    db.getTableDao().insertData(myTable);
}
}
```